# Toggle a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically if the url has `cl=true`, I want to toggle the checkbox

URL: http://localhost:8080/general-setup?cl=true

My code:

```
//auto toggle clone if cl=true
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.contains('cl=true')) {
    $('#existingImageToggler').click();
}
```

I got a error:

> Uncaught TypeError: url.contains is not a function

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: url.contains is not a function

Comment: Check my implementation it uses includes and works as you'd expect :) if you need any help let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet,

```
//auto toggle clone if cl=true
if(window.location.href.contains("cl=true")) {
     var inputs = document.getElementsById("existingImageToggler");
    inputs[i].checked = !inputs[i].checked;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href.contains is not a function

Comment: @user9478626 its fine at my side in chrome, which browser you are singi?

Answer (score 0):

Convert URL to string and taht string to lowercase than check using **contains** methode

```
if("http://localhost:8080/general-setup?cl=true".toLowerCase().contains("cl=true")){
   //logic
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be helpful, there are some worthwhile points that should be included here. e.g. the first option fails if there are any other parameters in the query string, and both would fail based on capitalisation, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("cl=true") > -1) {
     $('#existingImageToggler').prop('checked', true);
}
```

this is very basic checking if url contains `cl=true`

Comment: this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf`

```js
var txt ='http://localhost:8080/general-setup?cl=true';
if (txt.indexOf('cl=true') != -1) {
  console.log($('#existingImageToggler').click());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='existingImageToggler'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the checkbox, you can use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function.

```
$('#existingImageToggler').prop('checked', window.location.href.indexOf('cl=true') != -1);
```

The second argument should be a boolean (`true|false`). Instead of making an if-else construction, you can also put the condition in there... saves you some code...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkid" name="">

<script>
//auto toggle clone if cl=true
var url = window.location.href;

if(url.search('cl=true') != -1) {
   $('#chkid').trigger('click');
}

</script>
```